# Ошибка при присвоении одного потока ifstream другому

Tags: c++, fstream, поток-ввода, ifstream

У меня есть два потока:

```
ifstream temp, in(*имя файла*);
```

Хочу присвоить переменной temp значение in.

```
temp = in
```

Но выдает ошибку:

**E1776 на функцию "std::basic_ifstream<_Elem, _Traits>::operator=(const std::basic_ifstream<_Elem, _Traits>::_Myt &) [с _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits]" (объявлено в строке 850 из "e:\Visual Studio 2017\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\fstream") нельзя ссылаться, так как эта функция удалена** 


Как это исправить?

Comment: Никак, объекты этого класса нельзя копировать друг в друга.

Comment: применением ссылок или указателей ifstream& temp = in; Когда вы перестанете называть обьект потока ввода переменным, представлять начнете лучше...

Answer (score 0):

Никак не исправить. Для этого объекта был запрещён оператор присваивания. Вы можете их сделать указателями на объект,например
`ifstream* temp,in = new ifstream(*имя файла*);`,
после чего можете спокойно пользоваться оператором присваивания. Однако помните, что in и temp в данном случае будут указывать на один объект и не забудьте вызвать оператор delete в конце блока, в котором были созданы эти указатели, при чем если на объект указывает более одного указателя, проследите, чтобы оператор delete вызывался только для одного из них.